# How to keep the unicode character codes in my csv file?

Tags: python, csv, nlp

I am handling a large number of incoming emails and many of them have various emoticons in them. I am planning to apply an NLP analysis on the user comments and train a classifier to provide relevant answers, instead of having to manually reply to hundreds of these messages. For this as a first step, I parsed all emails and saved their content in a list called `userMessages` that I wrote in a csv file. I plan to add further columns to the csv for analytic purposes, such as user name, address, date, and time but this is not relevant for this question now.

Here is the code I use to write the `userMessages` list into a csv file called `user-messages.csv`:

```
with open('user-messages.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, dialect='excel', encoding='utf-8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for _msg in userMessages:
            wr.writerow([_msg])
```

This doesn't run into an error due to the `encoding='utf-8'` parameter, however, it removes/recodes the emoticons in such a way that it is no longer retraceable, for instance in the following format: `ðŸ˜`. Ideally, I would like to have the original unicode codes in the csv file, such as `'\U0001f604'` (smiling face with open mouth and smiling eyes) and later substitute these codes with their (approximate) meaning for the NLP to better understand the context of the messages, for instance in the case of this character (`'\U0001f604'`), remove the code and add the words 'smile' or 'happy'.

Can this be achieved? Or am I overcomplicating things? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:** I am using Windows and I open the csv files in Microsoft Excel 2016.

Comment: How are you viewing the csv file?

Comment: Using Microsoft Excel 2016 on Windows.

Comment: Could be that your file is fine but excel is asumming another encoding because ut8 is not the default in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really encourage replacing these Unicode characters with their meaning now, rather than keeping the Unicode as a string (which can be simply done by adding the escape character `\`) and convert them later.

Replacing the Unicode with their meaning can be done easily using `unicodedata.name()` method like so:

```py
import unicodedata

def normalize_unicode(text):
    output = []
    for word in text.split(' '):
        try:
            meaning = unicodedata.name(word).lower()
            output.append(meaning)
        except TypeError:
            output.append(word)
    return " ".join(output)
```

Let's test out this function:

```sh
>>> x = "I'm happy \U0001f604"
>>> normalize_unicode(x)
I'm happy smiling face with open mouth and smiling eyes
```

Now, let's see how are you going to use this method in your code:

```py
with open('user-messages.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, dialect='excel', encoding='utf-8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for _msg in userMessages:
            wr.writerow([ normalize_unicode(_msg) ])     #<-- can be added here
print(normalize_unicode(x))
```